# How to stop people from editing save files

Tags: anti-cheat

(First, if this belongs on another stackexchange site, please say so.  I'm not sure if this belongs here.)

I am making a computer game.  It is a roguelike, meaning that once you die, your save file is erased.  You can easily cheat in these by just copying your save file and then restoring it once you die.  Of course, I want to stop people from doing that.  A few ideas I've already had are:

1. Encrypt save files.  This makes it so that people can only copy+paste files.
2. Have more than just a save file.  Have some type of "masterfile" that has information on how many games you've played, which ones have died, etc.  Once someone has died, the masterfile will detect someone trying to restore an old save file.

After this, though, people could just copy and paste the entire game folder from before and after and it would still work fine.  My next couple ideas are a little bit harder to do:

3. Use timestamps to detect when someone has edited a file.  The problem is that then people can't move the files at all.  I could have some type of "export/freeze" feature, but that could easily be abused.  Also, if some other program unknowingly edits the file could make the game think you're cheating when you're not.  I've also seen programs online that let you edit timestamps.
4. Use the registry to hold a bit of information.  I'm trying to make my game somewhat cross-platform and I don't know if there is even something like the registry on non-windows systems.  People could still edit the registry though.

Now, I recognize that there is no sure way to stop cheating.  I'm just trying to find ways to make the fewest number of cheaters possible.

So, my questions:

1. Are ideas 3 and 4 feasible?
2. Are there any other good ways to stop people from being able to edit/replace files?

Comment: *Of course, I want to stop people from doing that* - not of course. Why?

Comment: Rather than delete the file altogether, you could just wipe/reset its content. Or put a time-of-death timestamp in it. Then use a checksum/hash to thwart edits to the file. And then after you have done that, forget it and don't bother thwarting cheaters at all. People who want to cheat will usually find a way around any protection you come up with, and then they are likely to share that info with other cheaters. Unless you are a multi-million dollar game developer, or trying to protect user's financial or personal data, it is not really worth the effort trying to thwart cheaters.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Permadeath is one of the defining features of roguelikes.  They are built and balanced around the concept that once you die, your file is lost forever.

Comment: @Remy I think the first two things I mentioned do all that you said.  If I can find a way to stop people from cheating in other ways, I'll implement it, but if I can't find anything else I just won't worry about it.  I'm just seeing if there's anything else I can do.

Answer (score 0):

> How to stop people from editing save files?

You can't.

> I'm just trying to find ways to make the fewest number of cheaters possible.

Trying to stop cheaters will only encourage them, because the entire purpose of developing game cheats is to challenge yourself and making a better challenge only makes it more fun.

**But here is just a few tips:**

Encrypt/Obfuscate the save file with a really obscure method

Use a really obscure method of hashing the save file, store the hash somewhere else.  When loading the save file, compare against the hash.

Random idea: To make finding the second hash file more difficult and confusing, store it in the models/textures using the same file extension.  So when the game loads, it loads the textures and the hash file at the same time from the same directory.  This will make it hard to find for the average Cheat Engine user who doesn't have good reverse engineering skills.

Use simple antidebugging techniques such as IsDebuggerPresent()

To learn more techniques for Windows for anti-debug the best resource is:

The "Ultimate" Anti-Debugging Reference by Peter Ferrie